# How would you program this switchboard in your programming language of choice?

Tags: logic

These are the rules:

- `A` is `true` if `B` and `C` are `false`
- `B` is `false` if `A` is `true`
- `C` is `false` if `B` is `true`

The state of each is represented in code by a boolean variable or a closure that returns a boolean. At lease one of the variables must be true at all times.

---

I'm interested in clever ways to program this logic in different programming languages. I'm particularly interested in expressing the logic via bitwise operators, if that's possible. I'm not extremely interested in readability, although a concise and readable solution would be impressive.

If this question is too subjective for StackOverflow, could you please suggest a better forum?

Answer (score 0):

Fairly universal

```
if(b === false && c === false)
    a = true;
if(a === true)
    b = false;
if(b === true)
    c = false;
```

Guess it all depends on what controls a, b, and c.